# Discerning between to me and for me?

Tags: prepositions

> It is difficult **to** me.
>
> It is difficult **for** me.

Would you tell me when/ where you would rather use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know you want to play the violin, but **it seems difficult to me**.

which indicates an impression or opinion of being difficult.

I don't think you would say *It is difficult to me* by itself.

> **It is difficult for me** to understand what you are saying.

which indicates actual difficulty.